# What is a good free terminal multiplexer?

Tags: linux, terminal

Can you recommend some nicely developed terminal multiplexer.

Comment: Not really a programming question, is it?

Comment: Close enough I reckon.. we have questions about IDEs - and the linux terminal does expose a programming langauge

Comment: I agreed with Blortbeard.  A terminal is a tool that developers spend a lot of time in, so discussions about terminal emulators is quite relevant.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use [screen](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/screen/), a free terminal multiplexer developed by the GNU Project that will allow you to have several terminals in one.

Comment: Careful: I believe that the `screen` program has problems with Unicode, at least when it’s above the BMP.

Answer (score 11):

Another option is [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/), which is considered by some to be the replacement of the older "screen".

Answer (score 3):

There's also byobu - see:

- http://byobu.co
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byobu_%28software%29
- https://launchpad.net/byobu
- https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/byobu.html